# AngularJS ng-click. How to notify user that his ng-click is considered

Tags: angularjs, binding, angularjs-ng-click

I work on a mobile angularjs app. I need to load a new route on click on a `<a>` with a ng-href or ng-click. But when I click my app is waiting until the route is loaded to apply all my $scope changement. For example:

```
 <a ng-click='changeAScopeElements()' ng-href='#/page2'></a>
```

In this case the scope element that I changed is considered in the view after the route has changed.

I want to first change the scope element, apply it to the view (bind it), then I want to change my route.

Thank you for your help,

Stephane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is remove the ng-href altogether and take care of your tasks within the changeAScopeElements function and at the end of your actions in that function you could force the route change.

```
function changeAScopeElements() {
  return doAsyncWork()
            .then(function() {
                    //NOW go to page2
                    $location.path("#/page2")
                 });
}

function doAsyncWork {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

   // do your work here... once you are done run the following:
   deferred.resolve();
   return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: even with this solution the apply happend after the location path function is done.

Comment: See my edits above, I added in a function that returns a promise... because of that you can add the $location.path(...) in a .then block.